# How to upgrade from Centos 7.2 to 7.3 and not up to 7.4?

Tags: centos, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade CentOS 7.2 to 7.3 and I don't want to upgrade it to 7.4.
How can I achieve this?
Any hints are quite welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the mirror at *vault.centos.org* which provide snapshots of the releases. Also view the `readme.txt` on that site.

To make use of this mirror, you have to disable the default mirrors in */etc/yum.repos.d* by adding `enabled=0` to the specific repo configuration. Or move the configuration files to `.disabled` and recreate a new configuration file for the 7.3 repositories.

A sample repo configuration placed e.g. at */etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-7.3.repo* would like as follows.

```
[base-7.3]
name=CentOS-7.3 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[updates-7.3]
name=CentOS-7.3 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Depending on your needs you might want to add different or additional repositories. To see which repositories are active you can enter

```
yum repolist
```

After changing your repository configuration you should clean up the `yum` cache.

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Now when you update your system with `yum update` the RPMs at the 7.3 repository should be picked up.